# Page.Resolve is not working as predicted

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, iis, absolute-path

The ResolveUrl here works fine and generates the desired path `<a href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/HomePage.aspx")%>'>Home</a>`

But here

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

    upload1 = new SWFUpload({
        // Backend Settings
        upload_url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl( "~/UserProfile/Photos.aspx") %>',
```

the path is not generated properly just `/UserProfile/Photos.aspx` is placed there.

both are on different pages.

**Edit**
My desired output should to be `www.domain.com/UserProfile/photos.aspx`  when I use this method on my development mahine it works fine and generates `/applicationname/UserProfile/photos.aspx` but not with the production environment. The application on the production environment is `www.domain.com/wwwroot/Userprofile/photos.aspx`.
and the file SWFuploader is on the same Photos.aspx page.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, what is wrong between `~/UserProfile/Photos.aspx` and the returned `/UserProfile/Photos.aspx`?

Comment: I guess the question really should be - what are you expecting the output to be? it might be this isn't the correct method you need to call..

Comment: Sounds like you have a virtual path set up on your dev server (typically in the properties in your solution explorer) but not your prod server

Comment: @Darren please explain a bit did not understand. I am not very well with these paths related stuff..

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls - see my answer for more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a "Virtual Path" set up on your development server.

so - assuming that you're using Visual Studio's built in server. If you click on the root of your web site in the "Solution Explorer" panel on the right, then Right-click and choose "Properties Window" you will see the properties of your dev site. It looks as though you have a name in "Virtual Path".

you don't have this setting on your production enviroment.

If you prefer, set the virtual path in VS to "/" - it will then match your production environment.

If you want it so that your production environment has the virtual path then see this tutorial (assuming IIS 7)

[Create a virtual directory (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)